# I need primary key id after storing data instant

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working in search functionality here I need key id of currently stored data..
then select required data using of this key.
Use this function getting id=0 and the process used to get stuck.

```
onCreate(){
int id=getHighestID();
fetchData(id);
}
    public int getHighestID() {
        dba.open();
        final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
        Cursor cur = dba.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int ID = cur.getInt(0);
        cur.close();
        dba.close();
        return ID;

    }
```

is there any strategy to get data from database after recently inserted.

I solved the problem using

```
long id = dba.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME_SEARCH_VIEW, null,cv);
```

this return current inserted row id..

Comment: Call `getHighestID` in another thread otherwise it will block the UI thread. And your query statement is not correct.

Comment: thanqs for giving ur valuable time..plz can u write required query

Comment: SELECT MAX(_id) FROM table_name

Comment: thanks all of you gys i got the solution...  using                                                           long id = myDB.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME_SEARCH_VIEW, null,contentValues);      it returns current rows id ..